# Search for 'Games' in Dash to show Games from Applications Lens etc

Tags: 11.04, unity-dash, search

When I search in the dash for 'Games', I only get two. If I search for 'Internet', I get only a few results compared to what I get when I right-click 'Applications' in the dock and choose Games/Internet, etc.

Is there some way I can make dash show all these items on appropriate search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour.

- Dash only shows items you have accessed before (you search for things you once used/played/etc) and no we can, at the moment, not change that unless you want to open all games yourself by hand.
- The 'applications' lens, rightclick, games'  will open all installed games. Plus it will  show a selections of games you install. Searching here will search both too (installed and not installed).

Comment: Yeah, I get the default behavior, but I was looking to change it. It'd be nice I could somehow, for example, tag all appropriate programs so they show up when searched.

Comment: @Rasmus Sorry... no that is not (yet) possible. You will have to open each and every one of them.